# python : using gettext everywhere with __init__.py

Tags: python, gettext

I would like to use gettext through my application.

So, I tried to put the basics into __ init__.py like this :

```
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext

gettext.bindtextdomain ( 'brainz', '../datas/translations/' )
gettext.textdomain ( 'brainz' )
```

And I try simple call in Brainz.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from brainz import *

##
# Main class of the game
class Brainz :

    def __init__ ( self ) :

        print _( "BrainZ" )
        print _( "There will be blood..." )
        print _( "By %s" ) % "MARTIN Damien"
```

But I have the following error at execution time :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    Brainz ()
  File "/home/damien/Dropbox/Projets/BrainZ/brainz/Brainz.py", line 12, in __init__
    print _( "BrainZ" )
NameError: global name '_' is not defined
```

As I'm new to python I don't understand what is wrong.

Could you give me good advices ?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: Why are you naming your data directory `datas`? Data has no plural form. "Datas" is like saying "moneys" or "peoples"

Comment: Also, don't use ".py" (or any other suffix/extension) when naming your executable/launcher files, as you did with `Brainz.py`. It should be named like any other shell command: `brainz`. No caps, no extension. So if tomorrow you replace that with a bash script, or perl, or C, the launch command will still be the same. An executable is an executable, regardless of which language it was written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sdolan [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834545/624066) why your code didn't work, and provided a great solution. But it has an inconvenience: you have to import gettext in *every module you want to enable translations*.

Elf Sternberg [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835000/624066) a very convenient approach: manually make gettext visible project-wide. But it looks a bit cryptic and, as he said, it is pure evil :). He also suggests, for an unknown reason, the totally unrelated Django ugettext. No need of Django, stick with the standard lib gettext like you did before.

May I suggest a 3rd, [officially endorsed](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html?highlight=gettext#localizing-your-application) approach? In the same `__init__.py` you tried before, use this:

```
import gettext
gettext.install('brainz', '../datas/translations/')
```

***And that's it!*** Project-wide `_()` availability, in a non-cryptic, elegant and convenient way, using the standard `gettext` module. But, to be fair, if you look at gettext's source code, you'll see that uses the same trick Elf suggested. So, in essence, this is also Pure Evil(tm). But this is perfectly fine *if 'brainz' module is only used by your application and not meant to imported by other applications*.

If you want to share 'brainz' with other applications, you should use sdolan's approach: import it in each module. But, again, instead of using `bindtextdomain` and `textdomain` like you did, I suggest this:

```
import gettext
t = gettext.translation('brainz', '../datas/translations/')
_ = t.ugettext
```

The difference is using gettext's Class-based API instead of the GNU gettext API. Take a look in the [official reference](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html) for why. The `install` approach is also part of the Class-based API.

Side note: you will notice the docs suggest using `pygettext` as a replacement for GNU's `xgettext`. **Don't!** Pygettext is *extremely* outdated and lacks several features. `xgettext` is much more powerful and flexible, and fully supports Python.

Comment: Yet, making `_` name available globally, although very practical, has a drawback that's good to be aware of: as argued [here (second note) by Django's folks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation), as `_` is commonly used in other contexts, like doctests, or unused local variable, this may lead to very confusing bugs (when doctests break in a file where there's no need for translations, it may take some time to remember about this globally installed `_()`...). Afaik, there's no way to choose the function's name when using `.install()`.

Answer (score 5):

Wildcard imports don't import anything beginning with an underscore.

Wildcards are bad, they pollute the namespace, and create hard to find bugs.  Also, the `_` is sometimes used to denote an unused variable.

Just do the import where you need it.  It's only one line, so it's not hard to type in, and you could always create a snippet in your IDE.

*UPDATE:* See http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#importing for even more reasons not to use wildcards.

Comment: Thank you very much, as you said, it is not so hard to add just a line at the beginning of the file. So I will use " from gettext import gettext as _ ".

Answer (score 4):

This is pure evil, but it does what you want.  In the *_init.py*_ root of your project, do this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
import __builtin__
__builtin__.__dict__['_'] = ugettext
```

And now the underscore *will* be ugettext everywhere.  The other answers have appropriate caveats; modifying the python VM's builtins list isn't very nice, and it surely will confuse the hell out of anyone who's not familiar with it.

Comment: For python 3: `__builtin__` has been renamed to `builtins`